# VBA Query for dynamic range in excel formulas

Tags: excel, vba

The formula is giving the value in excel by this VBA code but the range in below formula is fix:

```
Private Sub Formula update()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range

    Set rng = Range("B1").End(xlDown)
rng.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=TEXT(RIGHT(**B9**,9)+3,""DDMMMYYYY"")&"" - ""&TEXT(RIGHT(*B9*,9)+7,""DDMMMYYYY"")"
rng.Offset(1, -1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""WK-"",IF((WEEKNUM(LEFT(**B10**,9),2)-40)<=0,(WEEKNUM(LEFT(**B10**,9),2)-40)+53,WEEKNUM(LEFT(**B10**,9),2)-40))"

End Sub
```

however in below mentioned code I need a dynamic range under the formulas.

Can someone resolved it.

```
Private Sub FormulaValue_paste()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range

    Set rng = Range("B1").End(xlDown)
rng.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=TEXT(RIGHT(rng,9)+3,""DDMMMYYYY"")&"" - ""&TEXT(RIGHT(rng,9)+7,""DDMMMYYYY"")"
        Set rng1 = rng.Offset(1, 0)
rng.Offset(1, -1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""WK-"",IF((WEEKNUM(LEFT(rng1,9),2)-40)<=0,(WEEKNUM(LEFT(rng1,9),2)-40)+53,WEEKNUM(LEFT(rng1,9),2)-40))"

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your kind support.

Comment: *I need a dynamic range under the formulas* - can you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but if you mean you want the formula to refer to rng1, perhaps this. Use the Address property of a range and remove it from the quotes.

```
rng.Offset(1, -1).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""WK-"",IF((WEEKNUM(LEFT(" & rng1.address & ",9),2)-40)<=0,(WEEKNUM(LEFT(" & rng1.address & ",9),2)-40)+53,WEEKNUM(LEFT(" & rng1.address & ",9),2)-40))"
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Perhaps you could accept the answer please.